# Ajax request cause following : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I know there are a lot of related article on this and i had tried most of the suggestions from other sharing. Here is partial listing of my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cron").click(function(event) { 
        $('.update-body').html('<br />Performing updates...<br />')
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        var request = $.ajax({
           url: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/update/longprocessing',
           type: "GET",
           contentType: "application/json",
           beforeSend: function (xhr) {
           var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

           if (token) {
             return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
           }
       },
       dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function(status) {
       var msg = "";
       if(status.msg == '1')
       {
           msg = '<div class="alert alert-success">Successfully updated.</div>';
       }
       else if(status.msg == '2')
       {
           msg = '<div class="alert alert-info">No updates</div>';
       }
       $('.update-body').html(msg);
   });

   request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
     var acc = []
     $.each(jqXHR, function(index, value) {
       acc.push(index + ': ' + value);
   });
   $('.update-body').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' JSON.stringify(acc) + '</div>');
   });
 });
});
```

Processing.php is expected to takes an average of 40 minute to complete. Here is the problem, the code runs well and a success message is returned when i run XAMPP on windows 10 platform.

When i move the code to Linux under XAMPP, processing.php shows no error and runs perfectly fine (so nothing wrong with the php code) but when i monitor the network performance, when waiting (TTFB) time to first byte hit 15 minutes, the following error message : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) is generated somewhere in the jquery ajax code. I am using jquery1.12.3.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I also realize sometimes, my php function get called the first time and after 6 minute, it is called a second time followed by 503 service not available. It does not happen in xampp under windows but happens in linux. I am using laravel 5.2 framework as follows:

```
Route::get('/update/longprocessing', ['as' => 'UpdateProcess', 'uses' => 'Project\ProcessJobs@UpdateProcess']);
```

In my ProcessJobs.php, code as follows:

```
public function UpdateProcess () {
          Log::debug("Update Process started");
           $counter =0;
          //get path to linux folder
           ...
          //loop through folder to get all 35000 csvfiles
           foreach (xxx as xxx) {  
          //for each file, read content, process and write to a single common csv files.
              $counter++;
              Log::debug("counter value : " . $counter);
           }

         return response()->json(['msg'=>'1']);
}
```

Log file shows the following:

```
Update Process started
counter value : 1
counter value : 2
counter value : 3
...
...
counter value : 10000
Update Process started    <--- this is the second time it is called
counter value : 10001     <--- counter still continue from previous.
counter value : 10002     <--- log file stop here and server return 503 service unavailable error.
```

Comment: Check the [max-execution-time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) on Linux? Try [set_time_limit(5000)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in php script?

Comment: Tried that but no use. I realize another strange event happening. I have debug message telling me the function is called the second time 6 minutes after the first time it it called. And the server response with a 503 service unavailable. Any idea which part should i look into ? I am going to post more details about the code i am working on.

Comment: Try running the script with 1 or 10 csv files. In case it works, than the apache config is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help skobalijic, tested with 2000 csv files and it works. So not an issue with the php file. Was trying to figure out what is wrong with the apache config.

Comment: Anyone have any clue which apache config do i need to tweak ?

Comment: Maybe you should try to run it some other way, for example: get the total number of files, than using JS/AJAX call the script to execute 1-1000, 1001-2000, ... You can call `process.php` and it may return `{'status': 'ok', 'next': 'process.php?page=2'}` - make your life easier.